# How can I suspend and resume layout in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

How can I suspend and resume layout in WPF?
I heard that this is not necessary. But this is extremely necessary!

I process a lot of change positions, and if they are rendered one by one, it creates a delay effect.

Here are some code:

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(Draw);
void Draw(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Clean screen
   for (int i = mainCanvas.Children.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
   {
     if (mainCanvas.Children[i] is PlayerUserControl || mainCanvas.Children[i] is Image)
     {
           mainCanvas.Children.Remove(mainCanvas.Children[i]);
     }
   }
   //DRAW FLOOR AROUND
   FloorService.FloorEntity[] floorsAround = floorService.selectFloorsAround(Player.id);
   for...
   {
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/" + floorsAround[i].ImageSource, UriKind.Relative));
        mainCanvas.Children.Add(image);
   }

   //DRAW PLAYERS AROUND
   //Its similar as draw floors around.
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Alan, before you look for bounty hunters, put some time in adding more information to your question. Someone might come up with a better solution. You are going to have to add it even for bounty hunters! :)

Comment: @Alan Your problem isn't the lack of bounty, it's lack of detail in the question. My impression is that your solution(suspending layout) isn't what you really want, so people need more detail to find the root of your problem.

Comment: This might help: **[In WPF, what is the equivelent of Suspend/ResumeLayout() and BackgroundWorker() from Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82847)**

Comment: It's so simple, I already described it. For gamers this is even more simple.

Comment: There is no correct answer in there. And I've  tried every answer and didn't work.

Comment: @Alan: "It didn't work" tells us *nothing*. What specifically didn't work? How did the behavior you saw differ from the behavior you expected?

Comment: @Cody I process a lot of change positions, and if they are rendered one by one, it creates a delay effect. This still not worked.

Comment: @Alan, it may be simple in your mind, but you haven't communicated *anything* about this "simple" problem to anyone else. You keep repeating "creates a delay effect" without explaining what you mean by that. You refuse to provide a code sample that reproduces the problem. You won't explain what you're trying to accomplish. You won't even tell us whether this is a real problem you've run into, or just something you imagine to be a problem without ever having actually proved it. How can you expect anyone to help?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @Joe Unfortunately you are wasting your time.

Comment: I added the code now. If you could see, thank you.

Comment: @Joe, I added the code in there. If you could see. Thank you.

Comment: @Alan: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code

Comment: @Joe, unfortunately I don't have patience to write all these things. Thanks for patience.

Answer (score 13):

WPF is a **retained** composition engine. What it means is you don't have to do the rendering yourself hooking the `Rendering` event, but rather **compose** an image using nodes that you will put in a tree. See here for details on WPF architecture: [WPF Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441.aspx). I can assure you if you understand perfectly this document as well as the Layout System link Rick Sladkey sent, you should also understand why you should change your code if you want to continue with WPF.

If you play it right with WPF (ie: use dependency properties, override Measure & Arrange methods for example), you will see it's a very powerful engine capable of displaying thousands of nodes in the graphical tree. I suggest another useful reading: [ZoomableApplication2: A Million Items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

You haven't given enough information except to say that your "process a lot of changes".  But if you make all those changes:

- sequentially
- from the UI thread
- without calling `UpdateLayout`, and
- without returning

then no layout occurs in-bewteen those changes.  Therefore there is nothing to suspend or resume because layout is always deferred until after you return from making these kinds of changes.

So, if you are experiencing delays, then is is not because your are not batching your layout changes ala WinForms.  As a result, the only way to reduce the delay, if it is indeed due to layout, is to avoid unnecessary layout recalculations.  Again, without knowing what you are doing, it is impossible to suggest anything concrete.  But there are many properties you can avoid to might trigger a recursive layout pass.  See *Layout Performance Considerations* in this article:

- [Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx)

Comment: You can get good performance with WPF elements as sprites, and you can even change their position on every render to get the fastest frame rate possible.  You just need to re-use the elements from frame-to-frame and adjust their location by changing the fields of a render transform, not re-creating them from scratch each cycle.

Comment: In game develop, we don't use this technic, because it's difficult to know which object dissapeared of the window.

Comment: @Seva in game develop you don't use WPF either.

Comment: @d7samurai, that depends :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered removing the canvas from the window first which would hide it, then clear and re-add all your items to the canvas, then re add the canvas back to the window?

Answer (score 0):

He clearly posted enough info that even I with limited wpf experience knew exactly what he was talking about.

So in short, he has a process whereby elements are being added / or manipulated (I assume in loop) and he wishes to freeze the rendering process whilst in the loop as that is being performed because I assume 1. You can see the rendering taking place and 2. It’s slow

There was a post above that mentioned removing the canvas first... well that’s almost it.  Just set the visibility of the main parent to collapsed, perform the element add/manipulation, then make the parent visible