# SuspendLayout using C1 FlexGrid for WPF

Tags: c1flexgrid

I'm facing performance problem with C1 FlexGrid for WPF, on other third party I've always the SuspendLayout method to disable the layout update while performing operations on the grid... is there any way I can perform this with FlexGrid?

Answer (score 0):

SuspendLayout is a WinForms concept. You cannot, in good sense, apply the same for a WPF control. In WPF you don't do the rendering yourself, but rather compose nodes that you will put in a visual tree, and rendering would be handled behind the scene.

[*Rick Sladkey's answer to How can I suspend and resume layout in WPF?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576780/3331861)