# How to stop UI being locked when adding things to the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have 250 objects which are visual which I need to add to a `WrapPanel`. When I do this the UI locks for a few seconds which is not what I want. Is there a way to stop this?

```
private void ButtonClick()
{
   Foreach(Visual item in ListOfVisuals)
   {
      WrapPAnel.Children.Add(item);
   }
}
```

From my knowledge I can't create a new `Task.Run() => ButtonClick` to perform this on as the Task wont be able to access the UI.

Comment: Did you materialize the `ListOfVisuals` or is that creating new elements as you access them? i.e. can you optimize the creation before adding them to your wrappanel?

Comment: You should profile to see what exactly is consuming all of that time. 250 objects doesn't seem like all that much, I'm surprised its taking as long as a few seconds. I suspect that either enumerating `ListOfVisuals` is relatively time consuming, or something about your layout (e.g. a data binding or a large number of layout calculations) is causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue here is that a change notification is being raised for each item you add.

You need to databind `WrapPAnel.Children` to an `INotifyCollectionChanged` instance that implements an `AddRange`. The goal should be that the propery changed event is only raise once for the entire collection.

> The obvious answer is, of course, just write a method which iterates
>   over the input collection and calls Add for each.  But this really
>   isn’t the answer, because the question really isn’t about AddRange –
>   the question is really about raising a single CollectionChanged event
>   when adding multiple items

How do you implement this?

```
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> dataToAdd)

    {

        this.CheckReentrancy();



        //

        // We need the starting index later

        //

        int startingIndex = this.Count;



        //

        // Add the items directly to the inner collection



        //

        foreach (var data in dataToAdd)

        {

            this.Items.Add(data);

        }



        //

        // Now raise the changed events

        //

        this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");

        this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");



        //

        // We have to change our input of new items into an IList since that is what the

        // event args require.

        //

        var changedItems = new List<T>(dataToAdd);

        this.OnCollectionChanged(changedItems, startingIndex);

    }
```

*SOURCE:* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx

But wait, you cannot bind `Wrappanel` like that! You will need to use an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsPanelTemplate` is set to be a `WrapPanel`. See this example http://tech.pro/tutorial/830/wpf-tutorial-using-an-itemspanel

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <Image Source="Images\Aquarium.jpg" Width="100"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Ascent.jpg" Width="50"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Autumn.jpg" Width="200"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Crystal.jpg" Width="75"/>
  <Image Source="Images\DaVinci.jpg" Width="125"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Follow.jpg" Width="100"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Friend.jpg" Width="50"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Home.jpg" Width="150"/>
  <Image Source="Images\Moon flower.jpg" Width="100"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is more-likely because each `Add` call will cause re-layouting and redrawing.

In `winforms` solution is to use `SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout` when adding multiple controls and, typically, enable double-buffering to avoid flickering.

You can search for how it is done in wpf (to example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82847/1997232) is something). But I'd suggest you to simply hide (`Visibility.Collapsed`) container until you finish adding 250 controls. It would be cool to display some *progress indicator* (vector visuals animation or a simple *gif*), like

http://www.sponlytix.com/Images/Others/Loading.gif

Comment: Nope. Collapse will cause a redraw.

Comment: @Gusdor, yep, one redraw. Instead of 250. Isn't that beautiful? Or you mean something else?

Comment: the cost of that one redraw depends on your scene graph. A large implicitly sized graph will be a expensive to resize. I threw in an answer with my thoughts on the solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is on screen, but you need at least **one redraw** (following layoting of course). It's not possible to prevent it. You mentioning *resizing*, but I don't see where OP mentioning it. He has problem with initial displaying. For resizing of complicated layout different solution should be applied (using some sort of virtualizing). Regarding your solution: databinding is preferred in wpf, so it's better, but for existing code-behind code hiding container is cheap and should do the trick (emphasis on *should*, I don't really bother to test it =P).

Comment: Let me get this straight, you are telling me that for WPF performance it doesn't matter what is onscreen, it _should_ work, but you haven't tested it. I suggest you run that test. Ill go so far as to brand this solution a **hack**. Sorry :(

Comment: @Gusdor, but why? I am quite confident in my conclusions =). It doesn't makes sense to render/layout invisible. You have doubts - you test =P.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
{
    foreach(Visual item in ListOfVisuals)
    {
        WrapPAnel.Children.Add(item);
    }
}), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```